# xStream parsing xml to object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

I have an XML with attributes, but can not get to move from XML to Object.

```
<SERV tipo='req_identif_tarjeta' code='' msg_code='' nserie='1'>
  <TARJETAS>
    <TARJETA ntarjeta='1044212619' tipo_tarj='T' msg_tipo_tarj='TITULAR' estado_tarj='A'              msg_estado_tarj='ACTIVA' cliente_tar='9938' nombre_tar='ANDREA ANGELA ARAYA ALVAREZ' ncuenta='9931' estado_cta='A' msg_estado_cta='ACTIVA' cliente_cta='9938' nombre_cta='ANDREA ANGELA ARAYA ALVAREZ'>
    </TARJETA>
    <TARJETA ntarjeta=\"1021007693\" tipo_tarj=\"A\" msg_tipo_tarj=\"ADICIONAL\" estado_tarj=\"A\" msg_estado_tarj=\"ACTIVA\" cliente_tar=\"9938\" nombre_tar=\"ANDREA ANGELA ARAYA ALVAREZ\" ncuenta=\"636363631\" estado_cta=\"A\" msg_estado_cta=\"ACTIVA\" cliente_cta=\"636363634\" nombre_cta=\"BRUNO RANDON BALBOA BALBONTIN\">
    </TARJETA>
  </TARJETAS>
</SERV>
```

This XML is represented as this POJO

```
public class SERV {
    private String tipo;
    private String code;
    private String msg_code;
    private String nserie;
    private TARJETAS TARJETAS;

}

public class TARJETAS {
private ArrayList<TARJETA> TARJETA;

public ArrayList<TARJETA> getTARJETA() {
    return TARJETA;
}

public void setTARJETA(ArrayList<TARJETA> tARJETA) {
    TARJETA = tARJETA;
}   
}

public class TARJETA {  
  private String ntarjeta;
  private String tipo_tarj;
  private String msg_tipo_tarj;
  private String estado_tarj;
  private String msg_estado_tarj;
  private String cliente_tar;
  private String nombre_tar;
  private String ncuenta;
  private String estadocta;
  private String msg_estado_cta;
  private String cliente_cta;
  private String nombre_cta;

...
}
```

Using this code I can get XStream to find the 'tipo_tarj' attribute but I can not seem to find the text value of the TARJETA node.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.aliasType("SERV", SERV.class);
xstream.useAttributeFor(SERV.class, "tipo");
xstream.useAttributeFor(SERV.class, "code");
xstream.useAttributeFor(SERV.class, "msg_code");
xstream.useAttributeFor(SERV.class, "nserie");
xstream.alias("TARJETAS", TARJETAS.class);
xstream.alias("TARJETA", TARJETA.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(TARJETAS.class, "TARJETA");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "tipo_tarj");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "ntarjeta");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "msg_tipo_tarj");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "estado_tarj");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "msg_estado_tarj");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "cliente_tar");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "nombre_tar");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "ncuenta");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "estadocta");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "msg_estado_cta");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "cliente_cta");
xstream.useAttributeFor(TARJETA.class, "nombre_cta");
```

The answer has no attributes "TARJETA". Why can it happen? What should you do to make the "TARJETA" attributes appear?

Can someone help?